# Checkbox state do not change after button is pressed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, checkbox

I have a button that when it is pressed calls an ajax function with some parameters and then the ajax posts some values on the database. The user might use this form a lot of times before he leaves the application or refreshes the page. Up to now, this works great!

In my last update, I added a checkbox that will hold one more piece of information that I want to be saved on the database using the aforementioned ajax function. So, when the button is pressed, I check if the checkbox is checked and I send to the ajax function true or false. Up to now, this works great too!

What doesn't work great, though, is the fact that the last features works properly only for the first time! Every other time the user hits the button, no matter what the checkbox checked state is, it will submit the state it was the first time. It is like the checkbox.checked property freezes after the button is pressed for the first time.

It might be irrelevant, but I also tried the same with toggle buttons and I get the same issue!

Do you have an idea on how to overcome this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the code:
The form: It has 1 toggle button and 3 buttons that call the sendTask function.

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='button' style='margin-top: 5px; width: 216px; height: 40px;' name='yesterday".$category['id']."' id='yesterday".$category['id']."'>This one was yesterday!</button></div>
            <button class='btn btn-".$buttoncolor."' id='btn-spec-small' type='button' onClick='sendTask(".$category['id'].", &#39;1&#39;, yesterday".$category['id'].")'>0-15min</button>
            <button class='btn btn-".$buttoncolor."' id='btn-spec-small' type='button' onClick='sendTask(".$category['id'].", &#39;2&#39;, yesterday".$category['id'].")'>15-60min</button>
            <button class='btn btn-".$buttoncolor."' id='btn-spec-small' type='button' onClick='sendTask(".$category['id'].", &#39;3&#39;, yesterday".$category['id'].")'>60+min</button>
```

The sendTask function:

```
function sendTask(category, weight, checkbox){
    var ieri = $(checkbox).hasClass('active');
    TaskSubmit(category, weight, ieri);
};
```

The TaskSubmit function:

```
function TaskSubmit (taskidsubmitted, weight, ieri) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'submit_task.php?taskid=' + taskidsubmitted + '&weight=' + weight + '&ieri=' + ieri,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response !== "fail") {
            document.getElementById('score-label').innerHTML = response;
        } else {
            document.location = "index.php";
        }
    }
});
```

}

The problem is that this line:

```
var ieri = $(checkbox).hasClass('active');
```

only changes the fist time a button is pressed. All the other times keeps the first state (true or false).

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: As is, this could be a dozen different things. Please post relevant code - ie. the ajax, the html where the button sits, any more information like is the button dynamic, is it reloaded at any point, etc... this may seem silly, but these are all areas that could impact what is *not* working

Comment: Keep in mind, you can also make an example using both jQuery and Ajax in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). See an example using [Ajax here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/rcUea/)!

Comment: I just noticed, but the first button you have there is the checkbox?!?!?! Otherwise you have defined two objects with the same id, which will cause unexpected and broken behaviour. Id's should always be unique.

Comment: Checkboxes are created dynamically and they have id's like "yesterday1", "yesterday2", ..., "yesterday12". Here I posted the version with toggle button - not the checkbox, but the problem and the functionality are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
function sendTask(category, weight, checkbox){
    var ieri = ($(checkbox).prop('checked') != undefined);
    TaskSubmit(category, weight, ieri);
};
```

The browser -should- remove this property if the checkbox is unchecked. If this is not the case, use `console.log()` to find out what it is doing.

---

In your html, you are passing `yesterdaySomeCategory` to the function, instead of `"yesterdaySomeCategory"`. I am not sure what jQuery does with that, but the normal way of selecting an element is by `$("#yesterdaySomeCategory")`. Try changing it to

```
<button class='btn btn-".$buttoncolor."' id='btn-spec-small' type='button' onClick='sendTask(".$category['id'].", &#39;1&#39;, \"#yesterday".$category['id']."\")'>0-15min</button>
```

Comment: I still get the same problem. Your code works but only for the first time. The next ones uses the checkbox's first state (either it was true or false).

Comment: You haven't included the part of the code that should change the state of the checkbox. To 'check' a checkbox, add the 'checked' property. To 'uncheck' a checkbox, remove the 'checked' property.

Comment: Hmmm... The state of the checkbox is changed by the user only, not with code. Initially it is unchecked but then the user might check it or not and then hit one of the 3 buttons. Whatever he does the first time (check or no the checkbox), every time a button is pressed, the checkbox status remains the same.

Comment: Can you add the html of your checkboxes too? What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Checkboxes are: <input type="checkbox" id="yesterday1" name="yesterday1"> There are 12 of them ("yesterday1", ..., "yesterday12"). I am testing with the latest firefox.